# What are the most notable cases of Bitcoin scams?

Tags: trust, theft, money, fraud

Bitcoins can be easily used to scam people out of their money due to the inability to perform charge-backs. What are the most notable cases of Bitcoin scams that are known?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a list of the most notable scams, thefts, and hacks:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=83794

Answer (score 10):

Here all famous scammers/sites:

[List of Known Bitcoin Scams: Beware of Fraudsters!](https://medium.com/cryptopay/list-of-known-bitcoin-scams-beware-of-fraudsters-de8f7442acd0)

[Bitcoin Scammers list](https://www.cryptocoinsrevolution.com/bitcoin-scammers-list.php#.XESVhBjhV-E)

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at a graph of the value of 1 bitcoin, that huge spike and drop was caused by someone hacking Mt.Gox and selling everyone's bitcoins to him/her for $0.00, dropping down the value to $0, and it stayed low as more people sold their bitcoins to make sure it wouldn't happen to them. It's been slowly rising since then.

Comment: See #2 in this list: http://bitcoinmagazine.net/common-misconceptions-about-bitcoin-guide/